# ColdFusion - Nested Variable (dynamic variable read)

Tags: variables, coldfusion, nested

**Edit:** The QUESTION is a duplicate, but the ANSWER is not!

I have the following code:

```
<cfquery name="contact" datasource="thesource">
  SELECT * FROM #table# WHERE foo = '#bar#'
</cfquery>
```

and then later on (this is the problem part):

```
<cfloop from="0" to="9" index="i">
  <cfset thisvar = Evaluate("contact.check" & i) />
  <cfoutput>
    #thisvar#
  </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Upon execution, it throws a nice big "Variable contact.check0 is Undefined".  However, `#contact.check0#` will output just fine if hardcoded.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Note:
I have seen [Coldfusion - variable field name when looping through database query results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064305/coldfusion-variable-field-name-when-looping-through-database-query-results), and although the problem seems to be exactly the same, the solutions do not work.  As per the comments, I am also getting a "cannot be converted to a number" error.  I notice Tomalak mentions "a little catch", but never says what it is.  In the article he links to, I have tried every syntactically equivalent form, and it all throws an error...either cannot convert to a number or is not defined.

Also, I'm aware `Evaluate()` has overhead and "should not be used".  I'll take any solution that works, whether it has Evaluate in it or not.

This is on ColdFusion 9.

Thank you

**Edit:** while a similar question already had an answer, this question had a different cause.  See accepted answer below.

Comment: The correct answer in the link you quoted should work.  What was your code that produced the "can't be converted to a number" error.

Comment: Agreed, the code in that answer will work fine assuming your query contains the column names "check0,...check9".  *RE: I notice Tomalak mentions "a little catch", but never says what it is*  Yes he did. It is the edit where he says: "When accessing Query objects with the "angle bracket"-syntax, you must append the (1-based) row number index" ie `queryName["columnName"][rowNumber]`.

Comment: Do you have a column in the query named 'check0'?

Comment: It'd be great if the people who have voted to close this explained themselves. It seems like a reasonable question to me (and doesn't fall within any of the usual closing criteria).

Comment: @DanBracuk: `contact["check"&i]` yields "check0 can't be converted to a number"...as if it is expecting the numerical index to an array.
@Leigh: I guess I misunderstood the "when accessing..." comment.  Thanks for pointing that out.  In any case, `contact["check"&i][1]` doesn't work.
@ScottStroz: yes. otherwise a hard coded `contact.check0` wouldn't work.  Thanks for checking the obvious stuff though :)

Comment: What was the error message with contact["check"&i][1]?

Comment: @DanBracuk: same thing.  Cannot be converted to a number.

Comment: If `contact` is a query with records in, and `check0` is a column in that query, and `i` is `0` then `contact["check"&i][1]` _will_ return the value of `check0` for the first record. If you're getting an error then its because one of those things is not actually the case, or it's generated by something other than that expression. [Edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17054863/edit) to include the code that is resulting in this error. (**The actual code that is erroring**; i.e. copy the file, remove everything except the problem part, verify that it still errors.)

Comment: See, when I cut out everything but the problem area, it works.  I'm not sure what is causing it to break in the full file.

Comment: Put stuff back in one piece at a time.  That will help you identify the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ridiculous and absurd.  Working code (moved things around a bit):

```
<cfoutput>
  <cfloop from="0" to="9" index="i">
    <cfset thisvar = contact["check"&i][1] /> 
    #thisvar#
  </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

NOT working code:

```
<cfoutput query="contact"> <!--- this line here --->
  <cfloop from="0" to="9" index="i">
    <cfset thisvar = contact["check"&i][1] /> 
    #thisvar#
  </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Someone else had put cfoutput tags around the whole page.  While this normally wouldn't be a problem, they ALSO declared the query attribute.  This somehow overwrote the original query from the db.  Calling `contact.check0` worked just fine, but building the variable name dynamically, I think, was attempting to reference the cfoutput's query attribute.

Thanks to Peter Boughton for the suggestion to extract the problem code...which led me to this realization, and Simon for posting the syntactically correct code.  Points go to them.

Comment: That's certainly quite odd.  Perhaps `contact["check"&i][contact.CurrentRow]` would have worked in the <cfoutput query="contact">, but if you only want 1 row you don't need to loop over the query anyway and so doing it the way you have working would suffice :)

Comment: *..put cfoutput tags around the whole page.. they ALSO declared the query attribute.* Hm.. but nesting two "query" outputs is not allowed, so it sounds like there is still a piece missing. If you still have the full extract/repro case handy, I would be curious to see it as I have never run into that issue.

Comment: Actually now you mention it, I have had issues in the past where `<cfoutput><cfoutput query="..."></cfoutput></cfoutput>` triggered a compilation error.  I can't recall 100% whether that was in CF9 or Railo though.

Comment: I suspect the problem was because the inner query, which was ALSO named contact, was overwriting some aspect of the original query, fed by the database.  I don't know enough about ColdFusion to say that with any conviction though.

Comment: @Leigh: I was a little unclear about that, sorry.  They had the original query fed by the query.  Then, AFTER that, they opened up a `<cfoutput query="contact">` tag, which surrounded nearly all of the remaining logic on the page.  Inner `<cfoutput>` tags behaved as expected, but trying to dynamically build the variable name broke because of the `query="contact"` segment.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, standard blub about escaping inputs.  cfqueryparam exists for a reason.  That aside you can do this without evaluate.  Give this a try instead, including a check to make sure there is actually a result

```
<!--- make sure that there is actually a result --->
<cfif contact.RecordCount EQ 0>
    NO RESULT
<cfelse>
    <cfloop from="0" to="9" index="i">
      <!--- assumes that you want row 1 --->
      <!--- check.CurrentRow could also be used instead of 1 --->
      <cfset thisvar = contact['check'&i][1] /> 
      <cfoutput>
        #thisvar#
      </cfoutput>
    </cfloop>
</cfif>
```

I suspect that it is attempting to Evaluate the column without specification of the row number, while when hard-coding it you'll find it uses the current row.

**edit** as Dan Bracuk pointed out this is an exact duplicate of the question you linked in your question, [Coldfusion - variable field name when looping through database query results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064305/coldfusion-variable-field-name-when-looping-through-database-query-results)

Comment: *... attempting to Evaluate the column without specification of the row number* Yeah, but in CF9 `contact.check0` should short-cut to the value in the first row of the query. So it should not throw an undefined error - unless maybe the `contact` variable is overwritten with some other value *after* the query is run? FWIW, it worked fine for me w/CF9 either way.

Comment: That logic has not changed in recent versions of CF.  I would expect contact.check0[1] or contact.check0.1 to possibly Evaluate correctly.  I do agree it feels a bit inconsistent though - but then again there are other, better, ways to achieve your aim as indicated here and there

Comment: @Simonatmso.net: I copy and pasted your code. I get a "The value check0 cannot be converted to a number".  Also, for the record, I didn't write the db query at the top, so I didn't want to touch it.
@Leigh: I will check again to make sure `contact` isn't being overwritten, but since the existing code already worked (we are simply trying to make it more expandable for the future), I don't think it is being changed.  Still, I'll look again.

Comment: What would be REALLY useful would be a cfdump of #contact#, as that would let us see what you are dealing with.