# Concatenate sql column names with loop index in coldfusion

Tags: sql, coldfusion, concatenation

I want to concatenate sql column names with the index from a cfloop. I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
#["columnName" & indexVariable]#
```

Can this be done? Thanks in advance

I apologize, yes I tried this, no it didn't work.

I have an sql table with similarly named columns, col1, col2, col3, etc...
I want to loop through the results of the query using the index of a cfloop that's contained within a cfloop query. I'm going to dynamically create a table based on the results of the query. Example:

```
<table>
<cfloop query="sqlQuery">
<tr>
<cfloop from="0" to="11" index="i">
<cfif NOT isNull(#["columnName" & i]#)>
<td>#["columnName" & i]#</td>
</cfif>    
</cfloop>
</tr>
</cfloop>
</table>
```

Comment: in your SELECT list or where are you trying to do this? Can you provide some sample code of your attempt?

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work? That's often the easiest way to answer these questions. At the very least before asking the question you ought to have given it a go so you can provide us with the code and provide us with info like what happened instead of it working, etc.

Comment: @MattBusche I'm attempting to do this in a cfloop query, I want to dynamically create a table based on the results of the query.

Comment: You must have been using the wrong search phrase as [this is a very common question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064305/coldfusion-variable-field-name-when-looping-through-database-query-results) ;-).  Unless there are some other issues, voting to close as duplicate. Side note, *RE: didn't work* for next time, do not forget to include any error messages.

Comment: @AdamCameron Yes I tried this, no it didn't work. I tried many other variations of this, all to no avail. The errors I get end up pointing to other parts of my code simply because the syntax with what I'm trying to do isn't correct or stating that my column name is an undefined variable...

Comment: @Leigh The errors I get end up pointing to other parts of my code simply because the syntax with what I'm trying to do isn't correct or stating that my column name is an undefined variable.

Sorry if this is too simple of a question to be answered. I've tried searching for the answer, the syntax I presented was the best I could come up with.

Comment: (Edit) @JimmyGoodson - It is not that it is too simple. It is an issue a lot of folks have encountered too, so it has been answered several times before and is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).  Take another look at the link I posted. It shows the correct syntax for accessing query columns dynamically - which is exactly what you are trying to do. They just omitted the outer query loop.  Try modifying the example. If you run into problems, update your question with the new code and any errors.

Comment: Perhaps the answer lies in adding the variables scope to the equation `variables["queryname"]["constantPart" & variablePart]`.  Hard to tell because I find the question to be unclear.

Comment: @Leigh you're right, thank you for making me take another look at the solution you posted. Thanks to everyone else as well, hope I didn't take up too much of anyone's time.

Comment: @JimmyGoodson - You are welcome. Glad you got it sorted out.